# How to query text to find the longest prefix strings in SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, ansi-sql

I am using sparq sql. Let's say this is a snapshot of my big table:

```
ups store
ups store austin
ups store chicago
ups store bern
walmart
target
```

How can I find the longest prefix for the above data in sql? That is:

```
 ups store
 walmart
 target
```

I already have a Java program to do this but I have a large file, now my question is ***if this could be reasonably done in SQL?***

How about the following more complicated scnenario? (I can live without this but nice to have it if possible)

```
ups store austin
ups store chicago
ups store bern
walmart
target
```

and that would return `[ups store, walmart, target]`.

Comment: By prefix - looking at your examples - would you mean the longest string before the last blank between words?

Comment: yes, that is right

Comment: why are you tagging mysqli and postgresql. If you're looking for a SQL answer then this tag is enough.

Comment: just to add more audience as I did not get many views with just SQL

Comment: Do you need it to work on both Postgresql and MySQL?

Comment: the mysql and postresql tags were correctly removed by some one. I should not have added those tags in the first place. A SQL or  apache-spark-sql solution will be great

Comment: It would be helpful if a database could be chosen for this as there are very few ANSI SQL string functions. Do you have any preference?

Comment: I am using sparq sql, I could do SQL commads within that framework or some of its rdd functions

Comment: Would you be able to post the Java solution that you have already please?

Comment: The java solution is just the implementation of LCP (Largest comoon Prefix). It does not use any SQL or database related form and is pretty slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're free to create another table that simply has a list of ascending integers from zero up to the size of the longest possible string then the following should do the job using only ANSI SQL:

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUBSTRING(name, 1, CASE WHEN number = 0 THEN LENGTH(name) ELSE number END) AS prefix
FROM
 -- Join all places to all possible substring lengths.
 (SELECT *
  FROM places p
  CROSS JOIN lengths l) subq
-- If number is zero then no prefix match was found elsewhere
-- (from the question it looked like you wanted to include these)
WHERE (subq.number = 0 OR
       -- Look for prefix match elsewhere
       EXISTS (SELECT * FROM places p
               WHERE SUBSTRING(p.name FROM 1 FOR subq.number)
                     = SUBSTRING(subq.name FROM 1 FOR subq.number)
                 AND p.id <> subq.id))
  -- Include as a prefix match if the whole string is being used
  AND (subq.number = LENGTH(name)
       -- Don't include trailing spaces in a prefix
       OR (SUBSTRING(subq.name, subq.number, 1) <> ' '
           -- Only include the longest prefix match 
           AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM places p 
                           WHERE SUBSTRING(p.name FROM 1 FOR subq.number + 1)
                                 = SUBSTRING(subq.name FROM 1 FOR subq.number + 1)
                             AND p.id <> subq.id)))
ORDER BY id;
```

**Live demo:** http://rextester.com/XPNRP24390

> The second aspect is that what if we have (ups store austin, ups store
>   chicago). can we use SQL to extract the 'ups store' off of it.

This should be simply a case of using `SUBSTRING` in a similar way to above, e.g:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,
                 LENGTH('ups store ') + 1,
                 LENGTH(name) - LENGTH('ups store '))
FROM places
WHERE SUBSTRING(name,
                1,
                LENGTH('ups store ')) = 'ups store ';
```

Comment: Thanks, have no access to a system. will test it very very soon

Comment: Tried your code, on spark SQL, returned just "ups store", did not list [target, walmart], but when I ran it in your online site, it did return [target, walmart]. That is not a big issue though, I was just surprised

Comment: Hmmm that's strange, those values should be returned from the `subq.number = 0 OR ...` condition since in that case no prefix was found elsewhere.

Comment: The cross join makes it super slow

Comment: If you haven't already done so please make sure the table of integers has a primary key, i.e. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lengths (number INT PRIMARY KEY);`. Have updated this in the demo. One other possible minor improvement would be to start the list of integers at the minimum name length rather than 1 but this would be a bit fiddly as zero would still need to be included and wouldn't help at all if the minimum length is 1. ANSI SQL is very limited in functionality so there's not much else I can think of to recommend...

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your column name is "mycolumn", and your big table is "mytable", and a single space is your field separator:

In PostgreSQL, you could do something as simple as this:

```
select
   mycolumn
from
   mytable
order by
   length(split_part(mycolumn, ' ', 1)) desc
limit
   1
```

If you ran this query often, I'd probably try an ordered functional index on the table like this:

```
create prefix_index on mytable (length(split_part(mycolumn, ' ', 1)) desc)
```