# Select longest string for each user

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like this :

```
Clients   Cities
1         NY
1         NY | WDC | LA
1         NY | WDC
2         LA
```

So, I have duplicate clients with different cities (not in order, but with different length at each line). What I want is to display for **each** user the **longest** cities string. So, I should get something like this :

```
Clients   Cities
1         NY | WDC | LA
2         LA
```

I am a beginner in SQL (I use Spark SQL but it's mainly the same thing), so can you please how can I fix this problem please ??
Thanks !

Comment: are we allowed to create a new table and do it ?

Comment: @Rex5 YES of course ! If it gives the solution, why not !

Comment: I'm seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079042/how-to-query-text-to-find-the-longest-prefix-strings-in-sql) to form up the answer. See if the link helps you.

Comment: Is the `Cities` column really tab separated values  ?  IF that is the case normalize your tables/data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `max()`:

```
select client, max(cities)
from t
group by client;
```

Then you should fix your data model, so you are not storing lists of cities in a string.  That is not a good way to store the data in a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle that query (in MYSQL) by using `SELECT DISTINCT` statement,
As inside a table contains many duplicate values, I hope it will make it work!

For instance,

```
SELECT DISTINCT city_name FROM cities;
```

And continue.... this is my hint to lead you to the desired and great answer

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the connection between distinct and the longest string, no ?